# How to check Request::is('/new/*') in Blade view in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade, laravel-6

How can I check `Request::is('/new/*')` in a Blade view in Laravel 6? I have no sidebar on the home page. However, I want the sidebar on `domain.com/new/x` pages like `domain.com/new/231`.

Here's what I did, but it's not working.

```
@if(Request::is('/new/*'))
    @include('inc.sidebar')
@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to match routes or URLs? Can you show your routes in web.php?

```
@if (\Request::is('new/*')) { 
    // will match URL /new/231 or /new/x
@endif
```

Comment: **Route::get('/new/{newId}', 'PostController@display');**

`class PostController extends Controller`
`{`
`    //single page display`
`    public function display($id){`
`        return view('post');`
`    }`
`}`